# Is it possible to customize radius for a feature in Mapbox [html]?

Tags: web, mapbox

I am trying to have the icons be circles instead of squares using the web-implementation of Mapbox.  There doesn't seem to be a radius property?

Comment: Are you using Mapbox GL JS or Mapbox.js? Have you tried the [radius option](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/l-circlemarker/) of circleMarker or Circles, if you're using Mapbox.js? Or `circle-radius`, if you're using Mapbox GL JS?

Comment: I am using mapbox.js

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Mapbox.js, you can use L.circle to add a circle measured in meters or L.circleMarker to add a circle measured in pixels.

Assuming you have a map instantiated and assigned to the variable `map`, you'd call:

```
L.circle([10, 0], 200).addTo(map); // 10=latitude, 0=longitude, 200=meters
```

or

```
L.circleMarker([10, 0], 200).addTo(map); // 10=latitude, 0=longitude, 200=pixels
```

This is documented on [Leaflet's](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle) and [Mapbox's](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/l-circle/) sites.